# Are subgroups of a finite 2-generated group also 2-generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, generated by two elements. If $H\le G$ is a subgroup, must $H$ also be generated by 2 elements?

Comment: Excluding the trivial subgroup?

Comment: Wouldn't any group then be generated by infinitely many (non-distinct) elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symmetric groups $S_n$ are generated by two elements, namely the full cycle $(1\;2\;\ldots\;n)$ and the transposition $(1\;2)$. Every finite group is a subgroup of a symmetric group by Cayley's theorem. So, if the statement were true, every finite group would be generated by 2 elements, which is clearly false.

Comment: The smallest group which is not generated by two elements is $C_2^3$, with order $8$, and the smallest symmetric group in which it embeds is $S_6$. But one can embed it into something smaller; in fact the semidirect product $C_2^3 \rtimes C_3$, where $C_3$ acts cyclically, is generated by two elements, and $C_2^3$ embeds into it.